# How to use Java AWS IOT event SDK

Tags: java, aws-iot-events

I have an Apache Flink application and I need to get IOT event input description, build message and send it. I searched in AWS documentation, and I didn't find an example of code to use this dependency. How should I create the IOT event object and use it?

**POM**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iotevents</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.169</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data to IoT Events inputs, there is a different SDK `aws-java-sdk-ioteventsdata`.